# How to find the length or check if a list of strings in a square bracket is empty using bash?

Tags: bash, list, square-bracket

I have something like this

```
VIEWERS=[]
EDITORS=[]
ADMINS='["abc@email.com","xyz@email.com"]'
```

Which are then later passed to a .yaml file as a list
I want to add a check to ensure if none of the three are set then terminate and do not move on

However I cannot figure out how to check the list of such strings is empty or not via bash.
Whats the proper syntax. I cannot use round-brackets to these due to .yaml restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. Looks like you want defines arrays.
   That's done like this:

```
    VIEWERS=() or VIEWERS=(abc@email.com)
```

Once they have been defined, you can check if ALL of those arrays are empty like so:

```
VIEWERS=()
EDITORS=()
#ADMINS=()
ADMINS=(abc@email.com bcd@email.com)


if [ ${#VIEWERS[@]} -eq 0 ] && [ ${#EDITORS[@]} -eq 0 ] && [ ${#ADMINS[@]} -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "all empty arrays"
else
    echo "non-empty array"
fi
```

If you run the above , you will get: non-empty array, since ADMINS is not empty.

If, however, you comment out the 2nd ADMINS line and uncomment the first ADMINS line, you will get: all empty arrays.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple matter of comparing them to the string "[]". Note that since anything containing `[` and `]` looks like a filename wildcard expression to the shell, you need to use appropriate quotes to keep it from "helpfully" turning them into lists of matching filenames. That means double-quotes around variable references, and probably single-quotes around literals. Also, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special meanings/functions. So something like this:

```
viewers='[]'
editors='[]'
admins='["abc@email.com","xyz@email.com"]'

if [ "$viewers" = '[]' ] && [ "$editors" = '[]' ] && [ "$admins" = '[]' ]; then
    echo "They're all empty"
else
    echo "At least one array has contents"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

No I don't want to use round brackets since I have to pass it as inside square brackets to my kubernetes deployment further on
Is there a way I can do so with this format?

```
ADMINS='[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like so:

```
cat infile | cut -d"]" -f1 | cut -d"[" -f2 | sed -e /^$/d
```

(*NOTE: I ain't care, I like to start with cat sometimes for readability.)

First we feed the input with cat, then cut the field before delimeter ']', then out of the remaining bit we cut after the '['. Finally we throw in a sed line to remove empty lines returned by the null results from the cut operations.

*Edit:

After scanning your orphaned comment in the thread here... seems like you maybe want to keep the brackets. It would be helpful in the future to show your desired output imho. maybe this would work ok?

```
cat infile| cut -d"=" -f2 | sed 's/[[]]//g' | sed -e /^$/d
```

First, we read in the file... then cut for after the "=", then using sed, remove all results with empty brackets . and then finally another sed to remove empty lines from the results.